# Diffeomorphism invariance & solutions to EFEs

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, diffeomorphism-invariance

I’ve read (in Sean Carroll’s GR notes, and several other places), that general relativity (GR) is diffeomorphism invariant. By this, it is meant that, if $\phi:M\rightarrow M$ is a diffeomorphism, than (any) two metrics related by $\tilde{g}=\phi^{\ast}g$ (where $\phi^{\ast}$ is the pullback) satisfy the same Einstein Field Equations (EFEs). By this, I presume it is meant that (in the vacuum case) $$G^{\mu\nu}(g)=G^{\mu\nu}(\phi^{\ast}g).$$ How does one show this is true mathematically?

Comment: The tensor $G:=G^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu\otimes\partial_\nu$ satisfies your equation; its components do not. They need a factor of the Jacobian for every index.

Comment: Also you have to transform the stress energy tensor, too

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform So is it meant that $G(g)=G(\phi^{\ast}g)$ then (concentrating on the vacuum EFEs)? Also, I thought that, under an infinitesimal diffeomorphism, a tensor changes by a Lie derivative. In this case, $\delta_{X}G=\varepsilon\mathcal{L}_{X}G$, where $X$ is the generator of the diffeomorphism. For $G(g)=G(\phi^{\ast}g)$ to hold, this would imply that the Lie derivative of $G$ is zero, but I don’t think it is.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Having thought about this a little more, would the following be correct? Suppose that $g$ satisfies the vacuum EFEs, i.e. $G(g)=0$, then given a diffeomorphism $\phi$, any metric related to $g$ by $g=\phi^{\ast}\hat{g}$ also satisfies the same EFEs, since $$(\phi^{\ast}G)(\hat{g})=G(\phi^{\ast}\hat{g})=G(g)=0$$ that is, $G(\phi^{\ast}\hat{g})=G(g)=0$. Hence GR is diffeomorphism invariant. Is this right?